# How to activate/renew Ubuntu Advantage/ESM if you have HTTP connect proxy like Squid?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

How to activate/renew Ubuntu Advantage/ESM on Ubuntu 14.04 if you have HTTP connect proxy like Squid - so you get security updates again? With the older tool I get errors and/or timeouts with `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, I found out for myself:

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf  # check for proxy FQDN! Or create empty file!

cat /etc/environment  # check for proxy FQDN!

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra*.list*

sudo apt update

sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ua-client/stable  # press Enter

sudo apt update

sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-advantage-tools

sudo -E ua status

sudo -E ua detach  # optional

sudo -E ua attach <ID_VIA_SEE_IMAGE_BELOW>

### sudo -E ua enable esm-infra

### sudo -E ua status

### sudo update

sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

[image: Ubuntu Advantage/ESM]

https://support.canonical.com/selfservice/s/article/Obtaining-ESM-Credentials-And-Enabling-ESM-On-Ubuntu-14-04-LTS-Trusty

Also interesting:

```
# Livepatch with Ubuntu 14 und Ubuntu 16
# Sometimes sudo isn't enough -> sometimes you need a real root terminal!
#
sudo -E canonical-livepatch config http-proxy=http://<HOST>:<PORT>
sudo -E canonical-livepatch config https-proxy=http://<HOST>:<PORT>
#
sudo -E ua enable livepatch
```

```
# Landscape with Ubuntu 14 und Ubuntu 16
# sudo apt update
sudo apt --yes install landscape-client
sudo -E landscape-config -a <SUBSCRIPTION_NAME> -t $(hostname -f)
# Enter (Y)
# Enter (no Account-Registration-Key)
# Enter (HTTP-Proxy)
# Enter (HTTPS-Proxy)
# y (activate scripts)
# ALL (scripts for all)
# Enter (no Access-Group)
# Leave empty or continuous_use, reboot_ok, reboot_stops (tags)
# Enter (Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use ESM with my "good-old" ubuntu xenial (16.04) until I'll find time to upgrade to newer version.

I've tried to setup ESM multiple times and again with your instructions above. But anytime I'm getting 401 unauthorized error with apt-get/aptitude trying to install updates available for ESM packages available.

My subscription is active and valid showing 1 subscription active. Obviously no one can say why I'm still getting 401 unauthorized! And Ubuntu/Support refuses to help as they are only interested in selling not supporting.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/549987)